# QTableView view displays nothing

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am working with [SQLite](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qsqlite) from `Qt` and I can't seem to make code that is derived from one of examples to work properly. My [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#details) displays nothing, even though its `model` is by no means empty:

```
QSqlTableModel model;

initializeDeliveryModel(&model);

QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(&model);

//view->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(view));

view->setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Delivery Table"));
view->show();
```

Model initialization code:

```
static void initializeDeliveryModel(QSqlTableModel *model)
{
    model->setTable("DELIVERY");

    int t = model->columnCount(); //6

    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    model->setHeaderData(0,
                         Qt::Horizontal,
                         QObject::tr("ID"));
    model->setHeaderData(1,
                         Qt::Horizontal,
                         QObject::tr("Number"));
    model->setHeaderData(2,
                         Qt::Horizontal,
                         QObject::tr("Complection"));
    model->setHeaderData(3,
                         Qt::Horizontal,
                         QObject::tr("Has Arrived"));
    model->setHeaderData(4,
                         Qt::Horizontal,
                         QObject::tr("Dealer"));
    model->setHeaderData(5,
                         Qt::Horizontal,
                         QObject::tr("Price"));

    if (!model->select())
    {
        QSqlError err = model->lastError();
        QMessageBox::information(0,
                                 qApp->tr("Failed to select data from table"),
                                 err.text(),
                                 QMessageBox::Ok);
    }

    t = model->rowCount(); // 18 on the last debug
}
```

What am i missing here? Why would no columns and rows be displayed?

Addendum. The `QTableView` object is created from inside of button click handler of my main form. When I copied the code from example as it was (and put the code from main into handler), it ended up the same: no headers or rows were displayed.

Comment: Dj you add your QTableView to corresponding layout?

Comment: No. In fact, i showed it separately (so that it produced its own window). After separate form was created and QTableView was placed on it, problem disappeared.

Comment: Could you formulate what you've said as an answer? I'd like to accept it, which is currently not posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add your `QTableView` to corresponding form layout?

Comment: When i did, it filled as it should've.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did not initialize the model at the same time. If you initialize the model after associating with the view, it is your responsibility to call [`QAbstractItemView::update()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#update). Passing the default [`QModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#details) may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem, given that your QTableView widget is created properly, the model data is set, and it shows up as an empty box in your GUI. You need to call:

```
    emit layoutChanged();
```

after you set your data to the model. The table should populate after this.